# Docker: Unable to connect to elastic search form spring boot docker image

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, elasticsearch, dockerfile

Dockerized Spring Boot App is not able to connect to Elastic Search server running locally at default address and port. Following exception is thrown:

```
2018-01-20 07:10:38.529  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Gemini] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}], removed from nodes list

org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannelsLight(NettyTransport.java:967) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.6.jar!/:2.4.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:933) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.6.jar!/:2.4.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNodeLight(NettyTransport.java:906) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.6.jar!/:2.4.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLight(TransportService.java:267) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.6.jar!/:2.4.6]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:390) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.6.jar!/:2.4.6]
```

**Docker File:**

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/CryptoAPI-1.0.0.jar CryptoAPI.jar
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "CryptoAPI.jar"]
```

**Docker command to run the image:**

```
docker run --net=host cryptoapi
```

Comment: What does your Elasticsearch config look like?  It almost appears you are not binding your host  correctly in the yml.

Comment: So your ES is running on host? or on a docker container?

Comment: Point to 127.0.0.1 inside a container will not point to your localhost on your host, but to the localhost inside the sprint container. It can not find the ES.

Answer (score 1):

If you access `127.0.0.1` within a docker container - it tries to connect to itself (in your case container with spring boot tries to access its 9300 port). The container doesn't know and shouldn't know anything about surrounding environment - that's dockers core principle.

There are some workarounds, see this [thread on docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/accessing-host-machine-from-within-docker-container/14248). But general idea is that you shouldn't try to access host machine from within a container.

The proper way would be to start elastic search within a container, establish docker network and communicate between the two containers by their names (domain names within the docker network).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to connect them using bridge network.